# Printing a group of .tiff files referenced by name in an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I have a folder with over 100,000 tiff files, each files with specific number:

> 1001
>   1002
>   1003
>   1004
>   1005
>   1006
>   1007...etc

I have a spreadsheet with a list of specific .tiff files I need to print. 1001, 1009, 1010, 1503, 1258, 1254, 12548, 12232, etc.

How can I print all of the referenced .tiff files using the spreadsheet? Or how can I tell Excel to go to this folder and find all of those .tiff files and print them?

Comment: Are the TIFF files all the same dimensions and orientation? Do they need to be printed from Excel, or can Excel be used to build a batch file that will be run and use another program to print them?

Comment: all TIFFs are the same dimensions orientation and bites size, right now i am using the list on excel to find and print the tiff one at the time. i would like to tell excel to go find the tiff and print it, but whatever is easier.

Comment: @Juan: I'd suggest you simply export the file names to a text file, add `mspaint /p <path to file>` before each line, save as .BAT and run the batch file. If you want to do it from within Excel I'm sure you can use VBA to execute Paint with the /p argument to print the files.

Comment: Hi Karan, any ideas on how to create a VBA? i am clueless...